# blas/lapack/atlas in numpy on fedora

Tags: python, numpy, fedora, blas, atlas

I've compiled and installed numpy successfully. But when I enter the

```
import numpy.distutils.system_info as sysinfo
sysinfo.get_info('atlas')
```

command, all I get is:

```
lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_opt_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_opt_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
```

So my question is (1) can I configure the BLAS/LAPACK/ATLAS library without recompiling/reinstalling the package and (2) how can I switch between those?

(numpy is installed in virtualenv; BLAS and ATLAS are sudo installed from dnf).

Comment: This might not help you in your situation, but installing Anaconda and then installing packages with `conda` usually solves this kind of problem.